# Calculate the Euclidean distance for 2 different size arrays

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance

I have two numpy arrays with the dimension of  2*1 and 2*149. Which function should I use to calculate the Euclidean distance for 2 different size arrays?

Comment: Scipy cdist : `cdist(a.T, b.T)`.

Comment: Why did you comment out the headline?

Comment: This isn't Twitter